# SVG building library for Java

Tags: java, svg

Is there a Java library that provides a component-based way to create SVG documents?

I don't need to render SVG, all I want to do is to construct an SVG tree programmatically and in a type-safe way.

Comment: yes bhalu library is there you can download here   http://pioneer-soft.com/Download

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) should do just fine: its not just for rendering, you can do SVG construction/manipulation with it.

Comment: But which part of Batik? The DOM api seems to be just basic DOM operations, `SVGGraphics2D` doesn't seem to support everything (XOR composite filters for example).

Comment: Ah, so there is specific functionality you're interested in, clearly including XOR composite filters. Its been a long little while since I looked at Batik, but http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/ext/awt/image/SVGComposite.XorCompositeContext.html and http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/ext/awt/image/SVGComposite.html looks like they might be the basis of what you want. Does that do what you want?

Comment: I've only started playing around with Batik today, so I'm not quite sure how to use them yet. Although it's definitely the filter that I need, I was kind of hoping that there was an API halfway between the DOM and the Java2D one, where I still manipulate the DOM model directly but with a more user-friendly object representation.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of how to use Batik to bootstrap and manipulate the SVG DOM:

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/dom-api.html

Comment: I know about this, but this is just basic DOM operations, bulky and not-at-all typesafe. I'm looking for something like a thin object wrapper around this.

Comment: The jquery-svg library provides a good SVG "builder" API, and works with Batik: http://keith-wood.name/svg.html However, it's meant to be used from JavaScript, and is not type-safe. I'm not aware of such a library meant to be used with Java, but it would not be a difficult thing to build (I'd estimate about a day of work).