# adding items to existing svg image

Tags: java, svg, batik, plantuml

Good afternoon everyone;

I am currently working on a project in Java try to create a desktop tool. My question is I am now a using a framework(plantuml) to obtain svg formatted graph. However, I want to change a existing item(or component we can say) in svg output and display it another way(e.g adding details). I have done some research about this and I found two frameworks helps me to achieve my goal;

1.) http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/
2.) http://svgsalamander.java.net/

Questions;
Is there any other framework will help me to manipulate existing svg?
which one should I use and how should i use I am kind of lost. I don't know where to start exactly.

assumption is: i can not change anything about plantuml. So only thing that i have i an .svg formatted image.

Regards ...

Comment: See this SO question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657082/svg-building-library-for-java

Comment: I look this one before asking my question. Although, it is quite similar to my question. It does not mention about manipulating existing svg file from -another framework-.

Answer (score 2):

I heard about Batik and I know it is quite popular, but I have never used it. In the past I had to generate/alter SVG programmatically a few times in my program, either in Java, Javascript or C++. I always did it by hand, which means:

- Using Java's standard org.w3c.dom or some other DOM library;
- Using Java's standard org.xml.sax or some other SAX library.

SVG is an XML application, so it is very easy to manipulate using a generic XML API like the two listed above. You basically load the SVG file and start adding/removing/altering elements by calling appropriate methods of the API.

Here is a little example using SAX for Java. I realized that I'm a little rusty; the code seems to work but cleanup by SAX/XML/Java Gurus is welcome. It operates on an SVG file generated with Inkscape, a vector editing program, but the concepts discussed here apply to any SVG (or even XML in general) document. Basically it works by altering a stream of XML elements; it inserts a progressive label near to every object in the drawing.

SAX is event based; events are raised during XML parsing. The code handles 3 distinct events:

- **startDocument** is raised at the beginning of the XML document; we use this event to reset the progressive counter.
- **startElement** is raised at the beginning of an XML element; if the element is a **path** (a common element to describe shapes in SVG) we take note of its position (**cx**, **cy**; the qualifier **sodipodi** is the former name of Inkscape).
- **endElement** is raised at the end of an XML element; if the element is a **path**, we *raise* ourselves events that lead to the generation of the label. We use the SVG element **text** to add the label to the document.

  ```
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;

  import javax.xml.transform.Result;
  import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXTransformerFactory;
  import javax.xml.transform.sax.TransformerHandler;
  import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

  import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
  import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
  import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
  import org.xml.sax.XMLFilter;
  import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
  import org.xml.sax.helpers.AttributesImpl;
  import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl;
  import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory;

  public class SVGMod {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

      try {
          SAXTransformerFactory factory = (SAXTransformerFactory)SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();
          TransformerHandler serializer = factory.newTransformerHandler();
          Result result = new StreamResult(new File("Output.svg"));
          serializer.setResult(result);

          XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
          reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", true);
          reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespace-prefixes", true);

          XMLFilter filter = new XMLFilterImpl() {

              private int x;
              private int y;
              private int cnt;

              @Override
              public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
                  super.startDocument();

                  cnt = 0;
              }

              @Override
              public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                      String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
                  super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, atts);

                  if (qName.equals("path")) {
                      int xIndex = atts.getIndex("sodipodi:cx");
                      int yIndex = atts.getIndex("sodipodi:cy");

                      if (xIndex != -1 && yIndex != -1) {
                          x = (int)Float.parseFloat(atts.getValue(xIndex));
                          y = (int)Float.parseFloat(atts.getValue(yIndex));
                          ++cnt;
                      }
                  }
              }

              @Override
              public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                      String qName) throws SAXException {
                  super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);

                  if (qName.equals("path")) {
                      AttributesImpl atts = new AttributesImpl();
                      atts.addAttribute(uri, "", "x", "CDATA", new Integer(x).toString());
                      atts.addAttribute(uri, "", "y", "CDATA", new Integer(y).toString());
                      atts.addAttribute(uri, "", "fill", "CDATA", "red");
                      super.startElement(uri, "", "text", atts);
                      char[] chars = ("Object #: " + cnt).toCharArray();
                      super.characters(chars, 0, chars.length);
                      super.endElement(uri, "", "text");
                  }
              }
          };
          filter.setContentHandler(serializer);
          filter.setParent(reader);

          filter.parse(new InputSource(new FileInputStream("Input.svg")));
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    } 
  }
  ```

Comment: There are many other ways to manipulate XML (from XSLT to JAXB) too, but I agree with the basic idea.

Comment: I considered XSLT for a moment but I completely forgot about JAXB. Something like JAXB could probably be the best option.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, the thing that I don't understand does not these tools help us to reach specific objects easily in svg? Should try to use classical approach rather than using these frameworks for this purpose? Like every project i am suffering with time constrain.

Comment: It really depends on your goals; unfortunately I have only seen a few lines of Batik usage a few years ago and I have no idea of how steep its learning curve is. It shouldn't be that bad, though. You should start looking at some tutorial. On the other side if what you need to do is *really* simple, like adding labels under existing SVG objects, like in the example I wrote, you may want to give SAX a try. The only *drawback* of Batik (and DOM or in general tree-based APIs) is that it is DOM based, so if you XML file is *huge* you may have memory issues. Shouldn't happen with an SVG file though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for example damix911.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to go the modification of PlantUML route anyway.
In the PlantUML forum
* http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/plantuml/viewforum.php?f=1
you could ask for a plugin architecture that allows modification of the svg along the lines of PlantUML. This way your changes will be more "compatible" to what PlantUML does than if you just do your own modification approach.